# Краткое прилагательное или краткое причастие?

Tags: части-речи

Есть заголовок новости - "Мэр недоволен темпами очистки улиц города от снега".
В данной фразе "недоволен" - это краткое прилагательное, или краткое причастие?

Answer (score 3):

Мэр не удовлетворен темпами - значит. темпы его не удовлетворили. Краткое причастие. Совершенный вид. Прошедшее время. У слова "недоволен" глагольные признаки не определяются, формальных показателей тоже нет. Прилагательное. Полная форма - недовольный. В полном причастии всегда две Н (поскольку суффикс либо ЕНН, либо НН)

Answer (score 2):

*Безусловно, это краткое прилагательное. У кратких страдательных причастий прошедшего времени перед суффиксом "н" есть суффикс "а", может быть и целый суффикс "ен" или "т". Это формальные признаки причастий. Причастие должно быть образовано от глагола, у этого же слова другой путь образования (довольный -недовольный- недоволен), нет глагола "недоволиться" в русском языке. Недовольный - это тот кто испытывает недовольство, испытывающий недовольство, признак внутреннего состояния человека, нет у этого слова признака по действию, как, например, у причастия "испытывающий". Вывод: недоволен - это краткое качественное прилагательное,обозначающее признак эмоционального состояния человека, который может быть выражен в большей или меньшей степени (очень недоволен, немного недоволен и т.д.).

Comment: Гм. А как же глаголы "довольствоваться", "удовольствоваться", "неудовольствовались"?

Comment: Обратите внимание ещё раз на формальные показатели (суффиксы), о которых я писала. Посмотрите в справочнике, учебнике, как образуются причастия в русском языке.

Comment: Ну вот вам краткое причастие "уверен". Где тут формальные показатели, на которые вы ссылаетесь?  
По поводу образования причастий - я уже указал глаголы, от которых может/могло происходить, так что неубедительно пока.

Comment: Отглагольное прилагательное "уверенный" образовалось от страдательного причастия "уверенный", оставив при себе лишь признак предмета и утратив признак по действию. У него и есть формальный признак бывшего причастия - суффикс -енн-, в краткой же форме - суффикс -ен-: увер-ен.

Comment: Ну и что из этого следует? Я не про прилагательное говорю, а про признаки причастия в нашем случае. Замените "недоволен" на "неудовлетворен" в заголовке новости - прилагательное в причастие превратится?

Comment: Одно слово в другое не превратится.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, граница между отглагольными прилагательными и причастиями весьма расплывчата. Но главный критерий тут: является ли это признаком или действием. В данном случае "недоволен" - это признак, качество мэра, поэтому, скорее всего, это отглагольное прилагательное.

Comment: Я, если честно, исходил из этого http://repetitors.info/otvet/?t=8046  
То есть, если бы было написано "Мэр был угрюм, пьян и недоволен.", то вопросов бы не возникло - прилагательное и точка (тут действительно признак или качество). Однако в этом случае... Вопрос...

Answer (score 1):

Краткое прилагательное: каков? Сказуемое.

Comment: А почему именно "каков?", а не "выражает недовольство"?

Answer (score 1):

Вечная тема... И никогда не приходили к единому решению.
А всё потому, что существующие грамматики не дают однозначного ответа на этот вопрос, а стилистические, морфологические и семантические соображения - косвенны и неабсолютны.

Будь моя воля, я бы эти вопросы оставил за рамками современной грамматики. Но коль скоро ответ, видимо, нужен для каких-то практических нужд, то **причастие**. Прилагательное по классическим представлениям не сочетается с существительными в творительном падеже.

Это свойство даже предлагали сделать характеристическим - т.е. использовать как необходимый и достаточный критерий различения прилагательного и причастия. Признак не абсолютный, но в данном случае лучшего я не вижу.

=============
По прошествии нескольких часов таки увидел. Глагол "доволить" современными словарями не фиксируется вообще, даже как устаревший. Не знаю, достаточное ли это основание для исключения версии о причастии. Если да, то придется признать **прилагательным**.

Comment: Довольный, довольнее, более довольный, очень довольный, довольно - разве это не поведение прилагательного? (Степени сравнения. краткая форма, образование наречия). А где глагольные признаки - вид. время? Где значение процессуальности? В современном русском языке довольный - это  прилагательное.

Comment: Я видел ваш ответ и понял, на что вы делаете упор.  
Да, это более свойственно прилагательным. Но не абсолютно. 
Более или менее  работает только для образований от бесприставочных глаголов: *более груженая подвода - [более]груженная лесом подвода*. Для приставочных (а корень-то у нас "воля"!) уже не проходит: *Более загруженная лесом подвода*. 
Про наречия - вообще не очень понял. "Довольно" вряд ли стоит возводить к довольный, значения уж очень разошлись. Да и вообще признак очень сомнительный.

Короче, на ответа вопрос "причастие" или "отглагольное прилагательное" эта логика не даёт.

Comment: Вот если считать "доволен" обычным, не отглагольным прилагательным - тогда да. Но так вопрос, вроде, не стоит.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ:

Нулевым результатом матча остались недовольны (определение~~~) как игроки, так и болельщики.

Объяснение:

Полная форма слова "недовольны" — "недовольный" (какой?). "Недовольны" — это краткое качественное прилагательное, обозначающее признак эмоционального состояния человека, который может быть выражен в большей или меньшей степени (очень недоволен, немного недоволен и т. д.).

Прилагательное — это определение.

Подробнее [тут](https://znanija.com/task/34298158#readmore).